# Export HTML/CSS flyers as image or pdf to print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I'm creating a web based flyer designer for dog walkers to customize flyers to print off. It's very basic and uses jQuery to change the contents/text of a DIV to what they want on the flyer...

My problem is how to let them print the flyers. Ideally, they want to choose between 2 or 4 flyers per A4 page. Or to export as pdf or image to take to a printer. I've looked into exporting html/css as a PDF or image but can't seem to find anything that suits the situation.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I need to ask: What's wrong with the browser's built-in print dialog? It's often easy to print-to-PDF, and a custom print-only stylesheet would solve most formatting problems. Use a button to fire a JavaScript `print()` command to help the hard-of-computing and you're all done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webkit HTML to  PDF\Image should do exactly what you want:

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at that and it seems to be an application? I need something that's web based, where the user can click on export on the website and download or print the image/pdf. Can't work out if this can be done with wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: PHP can call the application on the sever then send the output to the client.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the `print` media type in the main stylesheet:

```
@media print
{
  /* style sheet for print goes here */
}
```

Or, separate the print styles in it's own stylesheet:

```
<link href="foo.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This allows you to define custom styles that are displayed when using the browser's Print dialog (File->Print...).  That way, your end-user can print to their printer, print-to-PDF (or Microsoft XPS Document Writer), or whatever else they want to print to, without relying on a 3rd party library that, from past experience, is subject to quirks and inaccuracies in converting CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

You have loads of options... here is just one, in case you want to export your webpage to PDF without much work:

[Recommendation? for our specific HTML -> PDF project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350835/recommendation-for-our-specific-html-pdf-project/4846457#4846457)

Answer (score 0):

Just for more options, there's also phantomJS, which uses webkit rendering engine as well.  QtPDF is the pdf engine it uses behind the scenes

http://phantomjs.org/

This assumes you have a server that you can execute command line scripts off of.  Ive used this recently in a project, and it works great for converting HTML->PNG.  Have not personally tested the PDF functionality extensively.